# Illegitimate Child

Tags: fiqh, nikah

Salam alikum wa rahmatu Allah wa barakhtu. I have made a big mistake, one I don’t know I can fix. I’ve had an illegitimate child recently with a woman of the book. I did not do nikah with her before intercourse and I was very lost in life in the past year. My child was born a week ago and I want to know if I can do nikah with the child’s mother after this. I really want to get an answer because I’m doing everything I can to repent and ask forgiveness from Allah subhanahu wa ta3ala.

Answer (score -3):

Allah (swt) is the AR-Rahman Ar-Raheem, he is the most forgiving and most merciful. You should do nikkah, especially since you have a child now. Yes, this was a sin, but Allah (swt) forgives. Keep making dua and changing your ways for the better. If this child brought you closer to Allah (swt), this was a gift. May Allah (swt) continue guiding you to the right path!